# TypeError execute_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunk_size'

Tags: django, ldap, django-rest-framework

I try to run ldapdb with rest_framework and get an exception:
Type: `TypeError at /users/`
Value: `execute_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunk_size'`
Location: `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__, line 54`

models.py:

```
import ldapdb.models
from ldapdb.models.fields import CharField, IntegerField

class User(ldapdb.models.Model):
  # LDAP meta-data
  base_dn = "ou=user,o=foo"
  object_classes = ['person']

  # user attributes
  uid = CharField(db_column='uid', max_length=8, primary_key=True, unique=True)
  employeeID = IntegerField(db_column='employeeID', unique=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.uid

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.uid
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import User

class UserSerializer(serialisers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('uid', 'employeeID')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from api.models import User
from api.serializers import UserSerializer

class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
  queryset = User.objects.all()
  serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from api import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view()),
]
```

and last but not least `pip freeze`:

- Django==2.0
- django-ldapdb==0.9.0
- djangorestframework==3.7.3

Answer (score 1):

The latest release django-ldapdb 0.9 supports Django 1.8, 1.10 and 1.11. It does not support Django 2.0.

The master branch supports Django 2.0 since pull request [#133](https://github.com/django-ldapdb/django-ldapdb/pull/133/files) has been merged, but there hasn't been a release since then.

Comment: I downgraded Django to 1.11.8. Now I get a similar error already when Itry to make migrations:  
   
TypeError: results_iter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked_fetch'

Comment: Since that error is on Django 1.11 it sounds like a separate issue. It's impossible to fix problems like that in the comments, you need to see the full traceback.

Comment: @ikreb I've updated. Happy to update again once there has been a release. Please remove your comment to keep the answer tidy.

Answer (score -1):

Please, install a newer version

```
pip install django-ldapdb==1.0
```

Now, the error should be away.

Comment: there is no release with such version number!

Comment: Please check the [changelog](https://github.com/django-ldapdb/django-ldapdb/blob/master/ChangeLog#100-2018-03-06).